# Hiding OSX Usernames on Login Screen

Tags: mac-osx, remote-desktop

I'd like to know how to hide a user from the OSX login screen. I'd like to have a hidden administrator account for using ARD, rather than the user's main account.

Any hints, tips and ideas?

Comment: To answer some questions for those who don't read to good, or look at the tags, or get humour when they see it - I'M TALKING ABOUT OSX - THANK YOU

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [your previous question](http://serverfault.com/questions/294493/can-i-create-a-hidden-admin-account-via-the-terminal-on-osx)?

Comment: I am humbled and ashamed, Thanks for reminding me Gorden - I just had a major memory failure. /* Sheepishly apologises to all */

Answer (score 3):

I can hide users in question by doing the following:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add 'newadmin'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could enable root, which would give you admin rights and not create an account at the login screen.

Comment: That would work, I'm sure - but I'd like to not have an active root user on 200+ "linux" boxes

Comment: @Mister IT Guru, make up your mind. Is it OS X or Linux? Similar != the same.

Comment: I know, I know, apple fan boys hate OSX, which is a BSD derivative being called linux! :)

Comment: @MisterITGuru: Nonsense. If you are looking for help, please be specific. As John said, OS X and Linux are somewhat similar, but not the same (by a long shot), so which one is it?

Comment: @SvenW Okay, keep calm here, please point out the nonsense? I think I was VERY clear in my question, OSX is the OS which I am asking about. I was also being jovial when I put LINUX, in " " - I was inferring, (as should be expected of every sysadmin with security in mind), that exposing the root user to active logins in A BAD IDEA. In this respect, the ENVIRONMENT EXPOSURE would be EXACTLY like linux, unix, and any other OS that uses similar architecture for authentication, and process control. I look forward to your followup comment. Thank You

Comment: @MisterITGuru: The sentence "apple fan boys hate OSX, which is a BSD derivative being called linux" doesn't make any sense at all, it is nonsense.

Comment: Okay -- Fine I just noticed an extra comma in there! I'm SORRY! Gosh!! That's not suppose to be there!! GOSH, WHAT A TROLL! The sentence should read "I know, I know, apple fan boys hate OSX which is a BSD derivative, being called linux!" It was a friendly nod to AFB's who respond to questions in the way you just did.